# "TypeError Cannot read property of undefined" on first submit of form in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am new to Angular and not so proficient in typescript so I'm struggling to see what's going wrong here. I'm writing a simple login form that asks 'username' and 'password' and calls an api in the backend to verify the credentials.

The api works and I am able to receive the correct response in my component as well, but only on the second (or later) "submit" of the form. On the first submit I get a `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`. From the second onwards, I get my console logging "Login Successful etc.."

I expect it to log the success on the first attempt though!
Since I get the correct response on the second submit, the api works so I imagine it being a sequential logic error or an actual typescript syntax error... any help is appreciated.

The component:

```
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private _studentService: StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  user: User;

  submit(name: string, pass: string):void{
    // console.log(name, pass);
    this._studentService.getUserByUsername(name).subscribe(data => this.user = data);
    this.verify(this.user.password, pass);
    }

    verify(checkPsw: string, pass: string){
      if (checkPsw==pass){
        console.log("Login Successful " + this.user.username + this.user.userID);  //logging this to see if the request comes through correctly since the ID is not in the form, and it is correct, so api works.
      }else{
        console.log(this.user.password, pass);
      }
    }
  }
```

The template basics:

```
<form (submit)="submit(username.value, password.value)">
   <input #username name='studUsrn' class="form-control">
   <input #password type="password" name='studPswd' class="form-control">
   <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

The service:

```
@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  private _restUrl: string = "http://localhost:4200/users";

  //make an http call and receive a response
  getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this._restUrl).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
  getUserByUsername(username: string): Observable<User>{
    console.log(this._restUrl+"/"+username);
    return this.http.get<User>(this._restUrl+"/"+username).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    return throwError(error.message || "Server Error");
  }
}
```

I also have a User interface for creating the user object.
I know it is not secure to handle credentials in this way, forgive me, for now I'm just experimenting.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the getUserByUsername method is asynchronous you need to call the verify method in the subscription as well, otherwise it gets called before the response is there.